# java.lang.ClassCastException with stream sorting and custom comparator

Tags: java, lambda, comparator

I am using java version 1.8, which supports lambda expressions.

I am trying to sort a stream by a custom comparator, but I am getting a ClassCastxception:

```
public class A {
    
    private String type;
    private String ip;
    private String originSubId;
    
    
    public A(String type, String ip, String originSubId) {
        this.type = type;
        this.ip = ip;
        this.originSubId = originSubId;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getIp() {
        return ip;
    }
    public void setIp(String ip) {
        this.ip = ip;
    }
    public String getOriginSubId() {
        return originSubId;
    }
    public void setOriginSubId(String originSubId) {
        this.originSubId = originSubId;
    }
}
```

```
    Comparator<A> defaultComparator = Comparator.comparing(A::getType)
                    .thenComparing(A::getIp).thenComparing(A::getOriginSubId);
    
    Set<A> entities = new HashSet<>();  
    entities.stream().map(e -> convertToB(e)).sorted(defaultComparator)
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```

**Error**:
java.lang.ClassCastException: A cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What are the types returned by `getType()`, `getOriginSubId()` and `getIp()`?

Comment: All of them are Strings.

Comment: What you are doing wrong, currently, here is, you are not sharing a minimal reproducible example for others to confirm the behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to extend the example. Somethings missing?

Comment: Should not it be ```A implements Comparable ```?

Comment: I understood from docu, that you can use Comparator instead of Comparable, so you can implement different ones.

Comment: But then I have also to implement and override method compareTo method

Comment: Might it be only possible for lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't collect to a "plain" `TreeSet` like that because it requires that the elements are either `Comparable` or that the `TreeSet` gets a custom `Comparator` on creation. You also don't need to sort in the stream, as `TreeSet` performs sorting on insertion. Your `convertToA()` method looks suspect too, is it converting `A` -> `A`?

You would need something like the following

```
entities.stream().map(e -> convertToA(e))
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet(customComparator)));
```

If your conversion method isn't needed, you can just forget the whole stream and do

```
Set<A> tree = new TreeSet<>(customComparator);
tree.addAll(entities);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I am sorry, the conversion method converts to another type like B. I added it in the post, so I need it. This is actually the reason for the stream. Now it seems to work correctly, thx!